# OpenMap tiles raster download

Tags: geolocation, qgis, openmaptiles

I have downloaded the single purchase raster file of the Australia-Oceania from Open tiles. The download has finished but when I attempt to open the file using GeoPro or QGIS I receive an error message that this file cannot be loaded. Can anyone help?
Shauna

Comment: Hey Shauna, welcome! The community may be able to help you better if you provide the exact error message you receive. Answering questions like what file extension, what steps do you take to open it, maybe even what version of applications you're using could all be helpful for troubleshooting. Again, welcome!

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that you have to open the file with the blob logo (second version of the file listed in the file browser) and since the data set is so big (6+ gb) it will take a **very long** time to open.

It's worth also posting a new question on their support forum:
https://support.maptiler.com/s2-desktop

Here's how I've come to this theory:

You've downloaded and installed QGIS from here 
https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

You've downloaded the mbtiles Australia map from here
https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/tileset/osm/australia-oceania/?usage=open-source

I found a guide for opening mbtiles in QGIS:
https://support.maptiler.com/i77-open-maps-in-qgis

- I open QGIS
- I click start a new blank project and
- then drag the .mbtiles file over into the main window that now appears blank
- dragging the file with the grid icon I receive an error message:

`` Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset C:/.../2017-07-03_australia-oceania.mbtiles: `C:/.../2017-07-03_australia-oceania.mbtiles' not recognized as a supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: C:/.../2017-07-03_australia-oceania.mbtiles ``

- When I load the australia-oceania.mbtiles file with the blob logo, it loads for a very, very long time (3+ hours). I have not been able to wait for it to completely load.

To see if opening a file like this actually works, I downloaded a sample .mbtiles file from this website: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/mbtiles/

Opening the version of the sample `trails.mbtiles` file from the website above rendered the same error. If I open the version that looks like a blob for the icon, it loads in QGIS right away. This leads me to believe the loading time just takes forever since the open tiles .mbtiles file is so big.

When googling large files taking a long time to open with QGIS there are several issues open for other file types. It leads me to believe this may not be different: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19509